# Booting Linux on iPhone

Tags: iphone, linux

I tried searching and searching and can't find a reason why one can't boot Linux from iPhone. I am not asking if there are drivers available for Linux or anything like that, I am just wondering why one can't boot Linux on a standard ARM processor ?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: There's more to a computer than just the processor. The operating system has to know how to control the device.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any such thing as a "standard ARM processor". Every ARM-based SoC is a little bit different, and Apple doesn't publish any information about how their SoCs work. (They aren't even standard Cortex-A designs; the Apple A6 and later all use CPU cores which were customized by Apple.)

Additionally, all of Apple's SoCs contain a bootloader in ROM which verifies a cryptographic signature before running any software from flash memory. This makes it impossible to run an operating system which was not signed by Apple.